# How to compile GCC on macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, gcc

I am trying to compile GCC9 on macOS Catalina. The closest tutorial I've found is [this](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/05/21/compiling-gcc-macos/) one.

The tutorial states:

```
In order to build GCC install the required header files in the old location:

1 cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/
2 open .
```

Command 1 doesn't work because my file structure is as follows:

```
 - Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode
 - Users/user/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices
 - /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/
- /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/
```

The package directory is not available.

Also, as can be seen, the `Library/Developer` path associated with my user has no `CommandlineTools`, while that directly on `Macintosh HD` does.

Should I run the above commands from root `/`? Or should the `CommandLineTools` also be available directly to my user?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're wanting to do this by hand rather than using a source distro with automation?

Comment: I've been having trouble for the past two days since the Catalina update, so I was trying the whole process over again by hand. Any reliable source distro with automation you would recommend? Thanks!

Comment: For example -- I run Nix (on Catalina, yes), so `NIX_PATH=nixpkgs=${NIX_PATH%%:*}/nixpkgs nix run nixpkgs.gcc9 -c gcc --version` installs GCC 9, and then runs `gcc --version`, emitting `gcc (GCC) 9.2.0`.

Comment: (since there's a prebuilt binary it uses that, but you can force it to really install from source if you want to).

Comment: ...if you want to go that route, see https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/2925 for discussion of changes to the install process pertinent to Catalina. (The `NIX_PATH=...` thing is also a workaround for a bug that'll presumably be fixed in a Nix release newer than today's version 2.3).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll look into it

Comment: (One handy thing about Nix is that you can have different sets of software installed for different projects / in different shell windows; if you want gcc 9 when you work on thing-A, and gcc 8 when you work on thing-B, and the default Apple clang wrapper when you *haven't* explicitly put your current shell into a different per-project mode... well, trivially done).